# Does the COPY command create an intermediate container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Does the `COPY` command create an intermediate container to copy the files just like `RUN` command? I did not find any reference to this in the docs.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/ 4th paragraph => `Each instruction creates one layer: * FROM * COPY * RUN * CMD`

Comment: Layer is correct. but is that layer created from baking an intermediate container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not actually create a container.

In the classic builder, [`Builder.performCopy()`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/e05fc8c/builder/dockerfile/internals.go#L155) goes through the steps of assembling an augmented image: get the base image, create a new layer, actually copy files into the new layer, and then construct a new image.  While there is a variable named `runConfigWithCommentCmd` this just sets the per-layer description that's visible in `docker history`.

Contrast this with [`dispatchRun()`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/e05fc8c/builder/dockerfile/dispatchers.go#L345) which actually goes through the mechanics of creating and launching a container.  Remember that a container fundamentally wraps a single command, and in the case of `COPY` there's not an obvious command that could be run (nor, for that matter, is there guaranteed to be any runnable command in the container at all; consider a `FROM scratch` image).